# Entity Framework Core 6 return Owned objects as null

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have a simple `Person` class:

```
public class Person 
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public Address Info { get; set; }
}
```

With property `Address` which is a simple [Owned](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/owned-entities) object:

```
[Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Owned]
public class Address 
{
   public string? Street { get; set; }
   public string? City { get; set; }
}
```

I can see the data being stored correctly in the database,
But when I try to retrieve a Person from my database `Info` is always `null.`

I am using the latest EntityFrameworkCore: v*7.0.5*.
And I am creating the database using 'add-migration', as intended.

1. I tried to switch all of Address's properties to non-nullable, and gave them default value, as this [issue](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/27516) suggested:

   ```
   [Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Owned]
   public class Address 
   {
      public string Street { get; set; } = "";
      public string City { get; set; } = "";
   }
   ```
2. I tried to retrieve `Person` using `Include`:

```
_dataContext.Persons.Include(person => person.Info).FirstOrDefault(person => person.Id = id);
```

I also added `OwnsOne` to my `OnModelCreating` method:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Person>().OwnsOne(person => person.Info);
```

3. Just for the sake of trying, I also tried using `int` instead of `string`
4. I tried annotating both the `Owned` object, and its properties with `[Required]`

But nothing helped, the `Info` was always `null.`

Comment: Do you run update-database?

Comment: Yes, I ran update-database after each migration, and I could see the data in the database updated accordingly.

Comment: Maybe there is a problem with the ways of Save data . I in this way and it was ok " Person pp = new Person();
            Address _a = new Address();
            _a.City = "sds";
            _a.Street = "test";
            pp.Info = _a;
            context.Person.Add(pp);
            context.SaveChanges();"

Comment: I am using Sqlite with "DB Browser", and I can see all the data being saved correctly in the database.
I can even take the raw SQL that EF 6 create, then execute it in "DB Browser", and I'm getting the data correctly.

Comment: What does your schema look like? Are the Address fields embedded in the Person table or do you have an Address table? If a separate table, what is the Address table using for it's PK?

Comment: The [Owned](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/owned-entities) annotation take care of it for me. the `Address` fields are embedded in the `Person` table.
The persons table will have the columns: `Id`, `Address_Street`, `Adress_City`.